# How to get video thumbnail from server videos?

Tags: android, server, video-thumbnails

Guys anyone please help me how to get video thumbnail from server side video?..

I Searched alot in stack but didn't get any useful solution?..

I used FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever this library.. I faced few errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

video thumbnail to server

```
   final File myFile = new File(selectedPath);
    Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    String thumbnail = getStringImage(bitmap);

//Server side
  params.put("thumnails",thumbnail);

 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```